# Can't archive with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I want to archive my app with selecting the Build Option "Generic iOS Device" (and i've done that a couple of times before i upgraded to Xcode 9.2) but unfortunatly it fails every time saying "No such module 'CryptoSwift'".

To make it clear, it doesn't have to do anything with SwiftyBeaver; it maybe have to do with my CocoaPods, maybe they don't like that libraries against the target. Or maybe with Xcode 9.2 itself.

To be more specific, it fails here:

```
import CryptoSwift //No such module 'CryptoSwift'
```

Whenever i select the simulator or a device (for building, not archiving), it compiles and everything works as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
    pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 0.8.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
    end
  end
end`

Answer (score 1):

The answere was in the first line of my cocoa pod file:

`platform :ios, '11.0'`

Instead of using 11.0, i changed it `platform :ios, '11'`.
And than i had to change the deployment target to 11.2. I don't know, what that was changed to 10.0 but those two changes did it.

So if you guys are using any minor versions of iOS in your pod file and you aren't sure, if it exists, just leave it blank!

Apparently it did cause those `No such module ''` errors, because the compiler wasn't able to build that frameworks in the Derived folder because it didn't know what iOS Version i wanted them to be built.